# includes php not working in HTML5

Tags: php, include

I've been attempting to use the includes/file_name.php feature for the navigation bar (& a few other places once I have the nav completed).

My navigation bar was the way it was suppose to be, until I started playing around with includes.  Now, it's not.

At first, when I started playing with the nav didn't show up. Now it does, but the styling is incorrect.

What's wrong with the code (I don't think showing the style sheet is needed, since it did work earlier, but did it for transparency)?

I've been using HTML5.

index.php (root menu)

```
<?php require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "includes/nav.php"); ?>
```

nav.php (inside the includes folder)

```
<head>
<link href="../css/news.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="cbs-news-live.html">CBS News Live Feed</a></li>
    <li><a href="abc-news-live.html">ABC News Live Feed</a></li>
    <li><a href="international-news-stream.html">International News Streams</a>    
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Local News Streams</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social Media Crowdsourcing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sitemap.html">Sitemap</a><a href="/sitemap/"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.clairwyant.com">ClairWyant.com</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have some value in $DOCUMENT_ROOT? Path exists? Which error do you have?

Comment: is it just me, or is there no opening <nav> tag?

Comment: maybe try $DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/includes/nav.php" and remove body and head

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your path is correct, Change nav.php to say

```
<?php
  echo <<<EOT  
    <head>
    <link href="../css/news.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="cbs-news-live.html">CBS News Live Feed</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc-news-live.html">ABC News Live Feed</a></li>
        <li><a href="international-news-stream.html">International News Streams</a>    
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">Local News Streams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Media Crowdsourcing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sitemap.html">Sitemap</a><a href="/sitemap/"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.clairwyant.com">ClairWyant.com</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
EOT;   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The included file gets insertet at the point you include it. as it is! So you probably end up having to head- and body-sections in your resulting file.

You do not need to quote the next in the included file. It can be plain html.

If you want to do it your way, your nav.php should only be this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="cbs-news-live.html">CBS News Live Feed</a></li>
    <li><a href="abc-news-live.html">ABC News Live Feed</a></li>
    <li><a href="international-news-stream.html">International News Streams</a>    
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Local News Streams</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social Media Crowdsourcing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sitemap.html">Sitemap</a><a href="/sitemap/"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.clairwyant.com">ClairWyant.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Put the css file into the head section of your index.php (you normally want to have an include in the head-section as well, to include the same css and js-files everywhere).
The is no starting tag  in your example.